# Is it possible to lock the bootloader without losing data?

Tags: root-access, stock-android, bootloader-lock, nexus-6p

Is it possible to lock my phone without losing the system data it has? I had previously unlocked my **Nexus 6p** to get root access, and have since despised the big yellow warning sign reminding me that my device is unlocked every time I restart my phone. I have downloaded over a hundred apps as well as movies, music, and other files that I don't want to lose, so factory resetting is not an option. I am running **Android 7.1.1 Nougat** with a TWRP custom recovery.

Comment: You could just do a backup and restore it afterward.

Comment: I'd rather keep my data completely if it is so possible.

Comment: "big yellow warning" you could just flash another bootlogo...

Comment: It would be great if that were possible. I don't believe it removes the yellow icon though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On **Nexus 6P** the bootloader relocking method is contains the `Factory Reset`, there is nothing to do.

If you are trying to relock your device you should see a screen like this: [image](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-F7exgcxU8lE/VjvGzD_aQhI/AAAAAAAB6DI/llF-5-b9tpo/w530-h942-p-rw/IMG_20151105_131253.jpg).

If you want to keep your files and data you should make a backup and when your device bootloader agian locked you restore it.

This is a normal behaviour but for example on **OP2** [there is a method](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/op2-unlock-bootloader-without-wiping-data-recover-3-0-2-bootloop-without-app-data-loss.449845/) to keep your data in save during the bootload relocking procedure.

Comment: I believe that the OP2 method is to unlock. Will it work the same for locking?

Comment: In the linked article there is a paragraph named: "UNLOCK/LOCK BOOTLOADER WITHOUT WIPING DATA​" so I guess it's a bidirectional method.